# Installing GDAL with Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, gis, gdal

I just did a fresh install of Anaconda3 and am trying to add GDAL/OGR. I've tried installing with both `conda install gdal` and `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`. In both cases, the install completes successfully, but when I import gdal, it raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is related to this error https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/219

You should use virtual environments, (at least in order to quickly test different configurations)

You can try one of the following fixes:

**1)**

From the issue it seems like a problem with vs2015_runtime which has to be 14 for it to work. So check your version of vc2015 runtime, if it is too high you can downgrade it by.

`conda create --name gdal_vs15_14 python=3.6.5`
(Here you can probably see what version of vs2015_runtime it installs into the environment)

`conda activate gdal_vs15_14`

`conda install -c conda-forge vs2015_runtime=14`

`conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

**2)**

Another  simple fix for now, is by using python 2.7 (which is of course not optimal, but at least worked for me for now as a quick fix)

`conda create --name gdal_py27 python=2.7`

`conda activate gdal_py27`

`conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

Comment: The command `conda install -c conda-forge vs2015_runtime=14` does not work as of Feb 2019. The error is: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - vs2015_runtime=14